# Regular expression to match a given (first name or last name or full name) before and after the the words 'plot' and 'over'

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to find all occurrences of given (First name OR Last name OR full name) before and after the words 'plot' OR 'over'.

The maximum distance between the given (First name OR Last name OR full name) and the words 'plot' OR 'over' is 10 words.

I have worked on this but, the result is inaccurate for names after the words 'plot' OR 'over'. But works fine for names before the words 'plot' and 'over'.

For example, I need to find either of the names Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker before and after the words 'plot' OR 'over'.

Problem: In the string 
`over was the the moon parker parker charlie parker charlie`

Only the first occurrence of name `parker` is found and the search ends. the names `parker charlie parker charlie` do not get identified.

(see regex https://regex101.com/r/KCcvew/12).

Comment: Are you looking for the closest names around "plot"/"over"? Or the first one before and the first one after? Which ones should be matched in `charlie charlie over parker parker`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `after the words plot *OR* over` ?

Comment: None of the strings in the example regex have both `plot` and `over`.

Comment: I need to find the closest names (max difference can be 10 words) @MalteHartwig

Comment: yes I need to find names near both words plot or over @UnbearableLightness

Comment: charlie charlie parker parker should be matched in 'charlie charlie over parker parker' @MalteHartwig

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/9jB2hu/3).

Comment: wow ! that's exactly what i wanted @UnbearableLightness.

Comment: You are welcome, I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern:

`(?i)(?=.*(?:plot).*|.*(?:over).*).*?(?=Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker)\K(?:(?:Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker)\s)+`

- `(?i)` Turn on case insensitivity.
- `(?=.*(?:plot).*|.*(?:over).*).*?` Positive lookahead for anything followed by substrings `plot` or `over`.
- `.*?` Match anything lazily.
- `(?=Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker)` Positive lookahead for any substrings of interest.
- `\K` Reset match.
- `(?:` Non capturing group.

  - `(?:Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker)` Non capturing group. Any substrings followed by whitespace. The pattern is repeated greedily.
  - `\s` Match whitespace.
  - `)+` The non capturing group is closed and the preceding pattern is repeated.

You can try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/9jB2hu/4).

Comment: Does this take the 10 word boundary into account? I know Op said it was what they were looking for, guess I am still not sure what the actual rules are.

Comment: It does not. That's why I posted it as a comment beforehand. Since OP said this is what they were looking for I posted it as an answer. He also initially said `'plot' and 'over'` when it should be `'plot' OR 'over'`.

Comment: Hi @UnbearableLightness, i also need to consider the 10 word boundary

Comment: I have edited the regex to adjust for 10 words boundary. pls check
https://regex101.com/r/AAtAwL/1/

Comment: I also found another problem,
In the string, 'over was the the moon parker parker test parker charlie', the regex  searches only till 'parker parker' and stops the search after the word 'test'

Comment: In any sentence you want to check whether the distance between `plot` or `over` and the first instance of `Charlie` is less than 10? Or is it the last instance?

Comment: For your second comment... you want to continue the search then? Skipping unwanted words? I am not sure that can be done with a single regex

Comment: yes I want to continue the regex search after finding the first search. Basically I want to search all occurrences of (Charlie|Parker|Charlie Parker) before and after the words (plot|over) at a distance of max 10 words